# Exclude multiple trials in a data set according to criteria of another data set

Tags: r

I have two data sets with different lengths, one of which contains information (condition) I need to exclude trials in the other. Data set b has multiple values for one trial, for which data set a only has one condition value, eg:

Data set a:

```
subj    trial   condition   
  1       1        2
  1       2        2
  1       3        3
  1       4        1
  1       5        4
```

Data set b:

```
subj    trial    value
  1       1       488  
  1       1       626 
  1       1       449
  1       1       813
  ...
  1       4       564
  1       4       763
  1       4       346
  1       4       545
```

I would like to exclude all the trials in b, where condition == 1 in a. So in this example, I would like to get rid of all values for trial 4 in b.

I understand that this:

```
exclude <- b[b$condition == 1] 
data <- a[a$trial != exclude$trial]
```

cannot be done due to the different lengths of both data sets. How can I tell R to exclude all trial multiples of data set b?

Comment: Can you show us final result for you example? As i understand you want to delete row in Data set "b" where subj = 1 and trail = 4? Because this kind of row has condition 1 in data set "a"? Am I right?

Comment: I would like to exclude all trials with number 4 in b since it is indicated in a that trial 4 falls under condition 1.

Comment: Is subject always equals 1?

Comment: No there are multiple subjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
subset(b, !trial %in% unique(a$trial[a$condition ==1]))
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much!